# What is the difference between using post_save signal or do the logic in view

Tags: python, django, django-views, signals

So I have the following code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from myapp.models import UserProfile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def auto_create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    created = kwargs['created']
    if created:
        profile = UserProfile(foo=foo)
        profile.user = instance
        profile.save()
```

what is the difference between the previous code and creating the profile on register view?

```
def some_view(request):
    #save the user and then
    profile = UserProfile(foo=foo, user=user)
    profile.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `post_save`, user profile will be also created when user account is created in other ways, for example:

- using `manage.py shell` console
- using django admin
- using some other view
- using third party packages, like python-social-auth

Comment: Interesting, but that's the only difference? I thought the signals were like events so they are executed on a different thread

Comment: Signals are executed in same thread, they're some kind of callbacks, so you can just execute some code when event occurs. Django itself have only one thread (not counting additional threads created by runserver, those are only for server reloading, serving static files etc). If you want something to be executed outside of web response thread, consider using some task manager like celery or built into uWSGI (accessible by django-uwsgi package).

Comment: All of things that @GwynBleidB listed can be done with logic in models. In your case, you should use signals because you should not override the Django's User model. But, it is harder to debug in signals then logic in models. So, you should use signals if you cannot do your logic in models.

Comment: But remember - some signals are fired not only on accessing model methods, but also on accessing queryset methods (`pre_delete` for example), so sometimes they are more useful than logic in models.